# Problems with Boost 1.59 mutable_constant

Tags: c++, boost

I followed this post: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/attributes.html

```
log( string nameValue) {
    attrs::mutable_constant< string > Name(nameValue);
    logger::get().add_attribute("Name", Name);
    Name.set(nameValue);
    cout << "name is: " << Name;
}
```

Only one time the Name attribute is set with nameValue and remains as contant for every.
So I using set() method to set new value.But the Name is not getting updated with new nameValue when we pass a new value in log() method.

Boost version: 1.59 and OS: Ubuntu 15.04

Any solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you attempt to add the attribute on every call, and only the first call actually succeeds.

The `add_attribute` method of loggers act similarly to `insert` on associative containers. It returns an iterator and a `bool` that indicates whether the new attribute has been added or an attribute with the same name already existed in the attribute set of the logger. In the latter case the insertion did not happen and the returned iterator points to the existing attribute in the set.

You should use the returned iterator to set the new value. You will need to use `attribute_cast` to convert the generic `attribute` wrapper obtained through the iterator to `mutable_constant`.

Comment: thanks Andrey this issue is solved. But I am still facing issue with boost log rotation is not working when we set append mode, I have raised in separate  question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34037325/problems-with-file-rotation-after-adding-append-flag-in-boost-1-59-log-v2